# Why does my file directory include '/bin'?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to find a file in a settings folder in my application. I have a xml file there. When I run the following code:

`XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"..\settings\Settings.xml");`

I get the `DirectoryNotFoundException` and the exception says not found at `\bin\settings\Settings.xml'.`, instead of above. I even tried the full root directory to see the issue, `C://...` but it still includes a bin folder?

How can I have it so it doesn't include the `bin` part?

Comment: Well how are you running your app? What directory *is* your app in? At the moment we have very little context.

Comment: Your Applications runs from "\bin\debug\". The ".." at the start will make it go up one directory --> "\bin\settings". So you either run it from the right directory or you add another "..\" to the path (during development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the build results in Visual Studio are saved in a folder like `bin\Debug`. Since you use a relative path that jumps one folder higher, you get `yourProjectFolder\bin\settings\Settings.xml`. That file doesn't exist, since it's presumably in the project folder, not the bin folder.

The typical way to deal with this is to make sure the files that are supposed to be a part of the content actually have Build Action set to Content.

Using a rooted path definitely works - most likely, you made a mistake somewhere; either the path isn't rooted at all, or you're doing something like interpreting the path as an URI rather than a file path. `XDocument.Load` takes a URI, not a file path - the proper way to reference an absolute path on the filesystem would be `file://C:/ThePath/Settings/Settings.xml`.

Comment: So if anyone is silly enough to turn off building the app, make sure you dont. This is the correct answer "Build action set to Content" worked anyways, after turning build back on...